# How do I write a regex for the following condition

Tags: regex, matching

- Should be at least 4 characters
- Should start with a character`[a-zA-Z]`
- Should not end with `_`
- Should only contain at most 1 `_` in the entire word
- The word can contain `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

I tried the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^_]$
```

But then I am wondering wether this could be made even smaller, and also I am not sure how do I set 'atleast 4 characters' constraint.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your pattern by omitting the last negated character class `[^_]` as that will match any char other than `_` and add a positive lookahead `(?=.{4})` to assert 4 character from the start of the string:

```
^(?=.{4})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{4})` Assert 4 chars
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a single char a-zA-Z
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match an optional `_` and any of the listed on the left and/or right
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cLklYk/1)

Comment: From OP: “Should be at least 4 characters”, “Should not end with `_`”

Comment: @Toto Ah yes, I have changed the last quantifier to `+`

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
^(?i)(?=\w{4,})[a-z]+_?[^\W_]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (?i)              # case insensitive
  (?=\w{4,})        # positive lookahead, make sure we have 4 or more word character
  [a-z]+            # 1 or more alphabet
  _?                # optional underscore
  [^\W_]+           # 1 or more alphanum
$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/F1ignP/2)

Answer (score 0):

The verifications can be done with a combination of *positive and negative lookaheads*:

```
import re

tests = [
    'abc', # too short
    '_bcde', # starts with wrong character
    'abcd_', # last character is '_'
    'a_b_cd' # too many '_',
    'abc&cd', # illegal character '&'
    'ab_cd' # OK
]


regex = re.compile(r"""
    ^               # matches start of the line
    (?=.{4})        # positive lookahead: matches any 4 characters (string must be at least 4 characters long)
    (?=[a-zA-Z])    # positive lookahead: next character must be [a-zA-Z]
    (?!.*_$)        # negative lookahead: last character cannot be `_`
    (?!.*_.*_)      # negative lookahead: cannot match more than one `_`
    [a-zA-Z_]+      # looking for one or more of these
    $               # looking for the end of the string
""", re.X)

for test in tests:
    m = regex.match(test)
    print(test, 'Match' if m else 'No match')
```

Prints:

```
abc No match
_bcde No match
abcd_ No match
a_b_cdabc&cd No match
ab_cd Match
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ld0UJq/1/)